# Excel - Getting corresponding value to another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to get a formula in Excel to search for the value in the green box using two inputs,

1. the temperature in the first column [in this example 19]
2. the corresponding value [in this example 872.7]

Thanks in advance.

[image: Capture1]

Comment: Is that a typo? `19` instead of `19.5` degrees celcius?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So index() with match() twice, once for row and once for column:

```
=index(A2:I24,match(19.5,A2:A24,0),match(870,A2:I2,0))
```

All ranges based on cell A2 is “Temp C”

But I would put 19.5 and 870 in cells
to make the formula more useful.

Also, the 3rd argument (0) in match can be 1 or -1 to get the closest result either larger or smaller.